# Windows XP SP3 32 Language/Encoding problems

Tags: windows-xp, 32-bit, language, character-encoding

In my messenger I have a group with the name "Conheçidos" but what I see in my laptop is "ConheГ§idos".

And I have also other discrepancies in Portuguese words that have é or ó or something with a ' in other programs.

I have set Portuguese as the default language and keyboard.

Anyone know how I can correct this?

Note: Even after changing "ConheГ§idos" to "Conheçidos" the next time I login I get the same word.

Thanks!

Anyone??

Comment: does this *only* happen in Windows Messenger?  what other applications are affected?

Comment: @~quack I think I have seen this behavior on other apps :(

Answer (score 0):

Try setting language for non-Unicode programs to Portuguese.

To do this:

You must be logged on as an administrator or a member of the Administrators group in order to complete this procedure.

1. Open **Regional and Language** Options in Control Panel.
2. On the **Advanced** tab, under **Language for non-Unicode programs**, click the language version of non-Unicode programs to Portuguese.